# HMAC SHA256 in C++ (DynamoDB)

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-dynamodb, hmac

I'm trying to connect to DynamoDB through the REST Web API and it requires me to generate a signature using HMAC-SHA256. I've got SHA-256 working, but I cant seem to get HMAC working, here is the C++ code (using OpenSSL)

```
string hmac(string key, string msg)
{
    unsigned char hash[32];

    HMAC_CTX hmac;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, &key[0], key.length(), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&hmac, (unsigned char*) &msg[0], msg.length());
    unsigned int len = 32;
    HMAC_Final(&hmac, hash, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hmac);

    stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        ss << hex  <<  ( unsigned int )hash[i];
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Here is the call to hmac

```
    /*********************************************CALCULATE SIGNATURE****************************************************************/

string AWS4 = "AWS4" + secretKey;

string Kdate = hmac(AWS4.data(), dateStamp);
string Kregion = hmac(Kdate.data(), region);
string Kservice = hmac(Kregion.data(), service);
string signingkey = hmac(Kservice.data(), "aws4_request");

string signature = hmac(signingkey.data(), stringToSign);

string authoritzationHeader = algorithm + " Credential=" + accessKey + "/" + credential_scope + ", SignedHeaders=" + signedHeaders + ", Signature=" + signature;
```

This is the Python code I'm basing it off:

```
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate    = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), date_stamp)
    kRegion  = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')

    print 'Kdate: ' + kDate
    print 'Kregion: ' + kRegion 
    print 'Kservice: ' + kService

    return kSigning
```

Given the same values they produce a different result. Can anyone help me as to why this is? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you actually *call* `hmac()` ? The Python code seems to prepend ``AWS4`` to the key string. That would seem pretty important for what this does.

Comment: At first glance, this appears correct. The only thing that seems different is the encoding, and that wouldn't seem to be something that would alter this. A crapton of debug outputs with conversions to hex chars looks like it isn't far off in the future.

Comment: Figured it out, one part was calculated with hmac returning a character string, and the second part was calcuated with hmac returning a hex string.

Comment: I suspected a binary-result vs a asci hex string result, but figured you were more familiar with the usage as you had it. You should post an answer so anyone else that may have a similar issue can learn from it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that DynamoDB calculates hmac in two different ways. The first returns a string representation and the second returns a hex representation

The hex implementation

```
string hmacHex(string key, string msg)
{
    unsigned char hash[32];

    HMAC_CTX hmac;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, &key[0], key.length(), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&hmac, (unsigned char*)&msg[0], msg.length());
    unsigned int len = 32;
    HMAC_Final(&hmac, hash, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hmac);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2)  << (unsigned int)hash[i];
    }

    return (ss.str());
}
```

the string implementation

```
string hmac(string key, string msg)
{
    unsigned char hash[32];

    HMAC_CTX hmac;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, &key[0], key.length(), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&hmac, ( unsigned char* )&msg[0], msg.length());
    unsigned int len = 32;
    HMAC_Final(&hmac, hash, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hmac);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setfill('0');
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        ss  << hash[i];
    }

    return (ss.str());
}
```

Amazon uses the hex implementation for all date, region, service and signing key. The string implementation is only used for the signature

Comment: Another thing to note is that the version of OpenSSL matters. Its possible to link in different versions of OpenSSL that compile but will produce errors at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Mike's answer has a bug.
Don't use std::strings `.length()` to find the length of the key when dealing with binary data. As binary data can have null character before the true end of the data. Either take in a `char` array and length as parameters for both key and msg. OR if you are using C++11, you can use `vector` to store the binary data.

Following is a partial implementation of Mike's answer with vectors as parameters-

```
std::vector<uint8_t> 
HMAC_SHA256(const std::vector<uint8_t>& key
           ,const std::vector<uint8_t>& value)
{
    unsigned int len = SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    size_t keyLen = key.size();
    size_t valueLen = value.size();

    HMAC_CTX hmac;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&hmac);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&hmac, (unsigned char*)key.data(), keyLen, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&hmac, (unsigned char*)value.data(), valueLen);
    HMAC_Final(&hmac, hash, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&hmac);

    return std::vector<uint8_t>((uint8_t*)hash,(uint8_t*)hash+SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
}
```

Comment: The bug pointed out doesn't exist. `std::string::length()` returns size of the string in bytes regardless of whether there are zero-bytes in it. The following code can demostrate this: `std::string s("\0Hello!", 7); std::cout << s << std::endl << "s.length() is " << s.length() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

```
static int C_hmac(){
    /**
    *   man 3 HMAC
    * */
    std::string data ="your's data" ;
    std::string key = "your's key";
    unsigned int hash_sz = EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE;
    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    unsigned char* digest = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key.c_str(), key.size(), (unsigned char*)data.c_str(), data.size(), NULL, &hash_sz);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<< std::setfill('0');
    for(int i=0;i< hash_sz ;++i){
       ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int) digest[i];
    }
    std::string final_hash = ss.str();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks