# Why is my signature different from Amazons example? (C++/REST/Authorization Signature Version 4)

Tags: c++, rest, amazon-web-services, authorization, digital-signature

I am following the examples given on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html)  and I end up getting the correct signature using the details given [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html) .

My problem is I get the signature `ced6826de92d2bdeed8f846f0bf508e8559e98e4b0199114b84c54174deb456c` correctly but, as soon as I use the same methods and change the variables for the GET example on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html), it gives me signature `c2eb7ddb12cb2c46489fdf97947e68b24c3716` instead of `f0e8bdb87c964420e857bd35b5d6ed310bd44f0170aba48dd91039c6036bdb41`.

This is C++ code using openSSL for HMAC and SHA256 hashing.

> ### The Test function

```html
void Test3()
{
 std::string date = std::string("20130524");
 std::string region = std::string("us-east-1");
 std::string service = std::string("s3");
 std::string request = std::string("aws4_request");

 std::string key = std::string("AWS4wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY");

 unsigned char* signingKey = EncodeHMACSHA256_2(EncodeHMACSHA256_2(EncodeHMACSHA256_2(EncodeHMACSHA256_2((unsigned char*)key.c_str(), &date), &region), &service), &request);

 std::string stringToSign = std::string();
 stringToSign.append("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n");
 stringToSign.append("20130524T000000Z\n");
 stringToSign.append("20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n");
 stringToSign.append("7344ae5b7ee6c3e7e6b0fe0640412a37625d1fbfff95c48bbb2dc43964946972");

 // Create signature
 unsigned char* signature = EncodeHMACSHA256_2(signingKey, &stringToSign);

 // to hex
 std::string sigHex = ToHex(signature);
}
```

> ### HMAC function

```html
unsigned char* EncodeHMACSHA256_2(unsigned char* key, std::string* value)
{
 const unsigned char* dataToHash = (unsigned char*)value->c_str();

 // Initialise HMAC
 HMAC_CTX HMAC;
 unsigned int hmaclength = 64;  // Length of the resulting SHA256 hash
 unsigned char* hmachash = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * hmaclength);
 memset(hmachash, 0, hmaclength);

 // Digest the key and message using SHA256
 HMAC_CTX_init(&HMAC);
 HMAC_Init(&HMAC, key, strlen((char*)key), EVP_sha256());
 HMAC_Update(&HMAC, dataToHash, strlen((char*)dataToHash));
 HMAC_Final(&HMAC, hmachash, &hmaclength);
 HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&HMAC);

 return hmachash;
}
```

> ### Hex Function

```html
std::string ToHex(unsigned char* value)
{
 int len = strlen((char*)value);
 std::stringstream stream;

 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
  char tmpStr[3] = { 0 };
  int res = sprintf(tmpStr, "%02x", value[i]);
  stream << tmpStr;
 }

 return stream.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HMAC function was causing the problem, I was converting the unsigned char * to a char * and taking that length which, would end as soon as it hit a zero thus giving a different length. Changed the function to include a length for the key and value.

The HMAC length was changed from 64 to 32 and passed 32 into the function for the key length.

To warn other people on the examples given on Amazon website, beware that the string to sign date is not in ISO format its the same date and time that you pass in the date header i.e. Mon, 06 October etc...

Answer (score 0):

We can alternatively use `vector` if you are using C++11. The pros of using `vector` is you dont have to keep track of the memory deallocation.

I have an implementation of the same here - [HMAC SHA256 in C++ (DynamoDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392257/hmac-sha256-in-c-dynamodb/41601493#41601493)